# Use "find" instead of "for - do - done" to search subdirectories as well

Tags: macos, find, pictures, extension

In OS X 10.8 I have a couple of folders with pictures but not all files have the correct extension, there are GIFs that are named JPG etc.

I have a one-liner that do the job for the actual directory:

```
for f in * ; do type=$(file "$f" | tr "[A-Z]" "[a-z]" | awk '{print $2}') ; mv "$f" "${f%.*}.$type" ; done
```

Now I'd like to use "find" instead to also search the subfolders but I always fail.

Any hints?

Comment: I should be more clear: Not "find" itself is my problem but the correct naming at the end when I need to use the "{}" from the find command instead of the "$f" from thr for-loop. Sorry for not beeing exact in my question.

Comment: Note for next time: You should've posted these comments under Bruno's answer instead. If they are below your question, nobody gets notified about them.

Answer (score 0):

In this case you can easily find files NOT matching the extension .jpg:

```
find . -type f -not "*.jpg"
```

You can also loop over the results and check if the files are actually jpg:

```
find . -type f -not "*.jpg" | while read fname; do
  if [[ $(file $fname) == *"JPG"*]]
    then echo $fname
  fi
done
```

Comment: You want to use `find … -print0 | while IFS= read -r -d '' fname`, see also http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs

Comment: Tnx Bruno, `while read` is a great way to solve this problem in the same way than `for do done` work. And if my question were only asked to get a pragmatic solution I'm with you ;-) But I really want to know how this could be parsed with `find`.

Comment: I am parsing with `find` and looping over the results with something else (`while`, `for`, whatever). In your solution you invoke find for each filename returned by `ls`.
Maybe you meant using -exec?

Answer (score 0):

The easiest would be to enable recursive globbing for files, e.g. in Bash:

```
shopt -s globstar
for f in **/*.*; do
    type=$(file "$f" | tr "[A-Z]" "[a-z]" | awk '{print $2}')
    mv -- "$f" "${f%.*}.$type"
done
```

This way you avoid having to parse `find` output. The problem is that if there are too many files, this command may fail as it could exceed the maximum size of a command line. This is because the file names in `**/*.*` are going to be expanded by Bash before the command is executed.

So the alternative is to use `find`, piping its output to `while` and `read`.

```
find . -type f -print0 | while IFS= read -r -d '' f
    type=$(file "$f" | tr "[A-Z]" "[a-z]" | awk '{print $2}')
    mv -- "$f" "${f%.*}.$type"
done
```

For some best practices working with lists of files, see: http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs

Comment: I never thought of that way! Tnx for this hint!

Answer (score 0):

I found this way for my prob but it's not really elegant :-P

```
find . -type f -name "*.*" -exec sh -c 'name=$(basename {} | cut -d. -f1) ; type=$(file {} | tr "[A-Z]" "[a-z]" | cut -d" " -f2) ; mv `basename {}` "$name.$type"' \;
```

Answer (score 0):

From the previous comments, I guess you are looking for a way to parse the results without looping over them, by only using find:

`find . -type f -not "*.jpg" -exec sh -c "if [[ $(file {}) == *'JPG'* ]] then; echo {}; fi" \;`

Comment: YES :-)  Tnx, I'll play with that.